# Is there any association of political scientists that publishes endorsements for elections?

Tags: political-science, endorsement

It would be interesting if political "experts" (such as political science professors) had certain stances they had a consensus on (in contrast with laypeople or non-experts). Is there any information resource where such expert recommendations (for example, what policies the government should enact, or favoured presidential candidates) can be seen?